# Why rvalue reference argument matches to const reference in overload resolution?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14, rvalue-reference

Potentially related articles:

- [Overload resolution between object, rvalue reference, const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961719/overload-resolution-between-object-rvalue-reference-const-reference)
- [std::begin and R-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959953/stdbegin-and-r-values)

For a STL container `C`, `std::begin(C)` and similar access functions including `std::data(C)` (since C++17) are supposed to have the same behavior of `C::begin()` and the other corresponding `C`'s methods. However, I am observing some interesting behaviors due to the details of overload resolution involving lvalue/rvalue references and constness.

`DataType1` is **`int*`** as easily expected. Also, confirmed the by with Boost's `type_id_with_cvr`. `const vector<int>` gives `int const*` No surprise here.

```
using T = vector<int>;
using DataType1 = decltype(T().data()); // int*
using CT = const T;
using DataType2 = decltype(CT().data()); // int const*

using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;
cout << type_id_with_cvr<DataType1>() << endl; // prints int*
...
```

I tried `std::data`, which can also handle arrays and non-STL containers. But it yields **`int const*`**. Similarly, `std::begin` returns a **const** iterator, even though `T` is not const.

```
using T = vector<int>;
using DataType3 = decltype(std::data(T())); // int const* Why ???
using CT = const T;
using DataType4 = decltype(std::data(CT())); // int const*
```

**Question**: What is the reason of this difference? I expected that `C.data()` and `std::data(C)` would behave in the same manner.

---

Some my research: In order to get `int*` for `DataType3`, `T` must be converted to non-const lvalue reference type explicitly. I tried `declval`, and it was working.

```
using DataType3 = decltype(std::data(std::declval<T&>())); // int*
```

`std::data` provides two overloads:

```
template <class _Cont> constexpr
auto data(_Cont& __c) -> decltype(__c.data()) { return __c.data(); }

// non-const rvalue reference argument matches to this version.
template <class _Cont> constexpr
auto data(const _Cont& __c) -> decltype(__c.data()) { return __c.data(); }
```

While resolving overloaded functions for `std::data`, `T()`, which is non-const rvalue reference, is matched to the `const T&` version instead of `T&` version.

It was not easy to find this specific overload resolution rule in the standard (13.3, over.match). It'd be much clearer if someone could point the exact rules for this issue.

Comment: Interesting. For `begin`/`end` this wouldn't normally be noticed, since you would never use them on an rvalue. You'd say `auto && __x = f(); auto it = begin(__x);`, so the argument is always an lvalue. With `data`, one might similarly argue that data without size is useless, so you need an intermediate lvalue, too.

Comment: But maybe you should file a library issue anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is attributed to overload resolution rules. As per *standard 8.5.3/p5.2 References [dcl.init.ref]*, rvalue references bind to const lvalue references. In this example:

```
std::data(T())
```

You provide to `std::data` an rvalue. Thus, due to overload resolution rules the overload:

```
template <class _Cont> constexpr
auto data(const _Cont& __c) -> decltype(__c.data()) { return __c.data(); }
```

is a better match. Consequently you get `const int*`

You can't bind a temporary to a non-const lvalue reference.

Comment: Thank you. I also figured out for this rule. But I don't quite understand the grounds of this rule. Is there any reason why non-const lvalue reference can't be bound to rvalue?

Comment: Still a temporary object can be modified by their member functions. I found this fundamental difference between member and free function amusing. (see my answer). Do you know if the standard says something about member functions being able to modify temporaries?

Comment: This is messed up. `std::data(T())` passes an *rvalue* to `data`, not an rvalue reference. "this would mean that you could alter temporary objects" - well, that's like the whole point of rvalue references, to allow you to steal the guts of temporary objects by altering them.

Comment: Thank you so much for finding the very specific rule.

Answer (score 2):

The only line that is mildly surprising is `using DataType1 = decltype(T().data()); // int*`.

...but it is still normal, *member* functions can be called on temporary objects without being treated as `const`. **This is another non trivial difference between member functions and free functions.**

For example, in C++98 (pre-rvalue refs) it was not possible to do `std::ofstream("file.txt") << std::string("text")` because `operator<<` is not member and the temporary is treated as `const`. If `operator<<` were a member of `std::ofstream` it would be possible (and may even make sense). (The situation changed later in C++11 with rvalue references but the point is still valid).

Here it is an example:

```
#include<iostream>
struct A{
    void f() const{std::cout << "const member" << std::endl;}
    void f(){std::cout << "non const member" << std::endl;}
};

void f(A const&){std::cout << "const function" << std::endl;}
void f(A&){std::cout << "non const function" << std::endl;}

int main(){
    A().f(); // prints "non const member"
    f(A()); // prints "const function"
}
```

The behavior is exposed when the object is temporarily constructed and used. In all other cases I can imagine, member `f` is equivalent to `f` free function.
(`r-value` reference qualifications `&&` --for member and function-- can give you a more fine grained control but it was not part of the question.)